# Ajax запрос к стороннему сервису через XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Пробую получить данные от сервиса Pixabay.

Запрос не срабатывает (ответ сервера 0)

[Простой пример на JSBin](http://jsbin.com/radoyonuja/edit?html,js,console,output)

Когда в параметрах запроса выключаю асинхронность через

```
xhr.open('GET', URL, false);
```

запрос получает данные.

Как можно сделать асинхронный запрос корректно?

P.S. Разобрался, код который будет запускаться после выполнения асинхронной операции надо включить в обработчик события readystatechange

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
         //код
    }
};
```

или как вариант в обработчик события load

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log( xhr.responseText );    
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я изначально был не прав. Заголовки для кросс-доменного запроса есть.

 Вот так будет работать:

```js
var searchQuery = "flower"
var URL = 'https://pixabay.com/api/?key=2668103-5fd953825a02c25d2f0581911&q='+ searchQuery + '&image_type=photo&pretty=true';
 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", URL, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        console.log( xhr.responseText );
    }
}
xhr.send();
```

Ваша ошибка была в том, что вы пытались вывести данные до того, как они были получены.

Answer (score 0):

P.S. Разобрался, код который будет запускаться после выполнения асинхронной операции надо включить в обработчик события readystatechange

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
         //код
    }
};
```

или как вариант в обработчик события load

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log( xhr.responseText );    
};
```